# Check if the MLE is unbiased and/or consistent

Tags: expectation, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be iid random variables with probability density function
$$f(k|\theta) =
\begin{cases}
\theta,  & \text{if $k=0$} \\
\theta(1-\theta), & \text{if $k=1$}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{with 0<$\theta$<1}\\
(1-\theta)^2, & \text{if $k=2$}
\end{cases}$$
Let $n_k$ be the number of observations for $k$ ($k \in (0,1,2)$).
We observe two estimators $T_1$, $T_2$ for $\theta$ defined as follows:

$T_1 = \frac{n_0}{n}$. $T_2$ is the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for $\theta$.

I've calculated the MLE, which is:
$$\hat\theta = \frac{n_0+n_1}{n_0 + 2(n_1 + n_2)}$$

Now I'm trying to find see if $T_1, T_2$ are unbiased and/or consistent. Thus I need to find $\mathbb{E}(T_1)$, $\mathbb{E}(T_2)$, Var($T_1$) and Var($T_2$).

My thoughts:

$$\mathbb{E}(T_1) = \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{n_0}{n}\right) = \frac{n \theta}{n}=\theta$$
So $T_1$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$.
However I'm stuck at calculating the variance. I know that Var(X) = $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$-$\mathbb{E}(X)^2$. But I just don't see it now. What am I missing?

And how can I calculate $\mathbb{E}(T_2)$ = $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{n_0+n_1}{n_0+2(n_1+n_2)}\right)$? Which $n$ am I supposed to use? And why?

Comment: You can get parentheses (and other paired delimiters) to adjust to the size of their content using `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @joriki thanks!

Comment: I believe the MLE should be $$\hat\theta = \frac{n_0+n_1}{n_0-2n_2}. $$

Comment: @Math1000 Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought the following
$$L(\theta) = f(0|\theta)^{n_0}f(1|\theta)^{n_1}f(2|\theta)^{n_2}$$ or using the log-likelihood:
$$l(\theta) = n_0 \log f(0|\theta) + n_1 \log f(1|\theta) + n_2 \log f(2|\theta) = n_0\log(\theta) + n_1\log(\theta) + n_1\log(1-\theta) + 2n_2\log(1-\theta)$$
And thus differentiating and setting equal to $0$ we have:
$$\frac{d l(\theta)}{d\theta} = \frac{n_0+n_1}{\theta} - \frac{n_1 + 2n_2}{1-\theta}=0$$

Comment: You're correct, I was missing a $-$ sign.

Comment: @Math1000 Okay :) But can you help me with calculating the expectations and variances? I feel like it's not that hard but I don't know how to proceed